# How to properly configure SQL Server Database For Windows Forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create Windows Forms Application and this is my first time building an application in Visual Basic. I am very familiar with developing websites in Visual Studio however, it appears that the database connection works much differently...

I am trying to build a simple data entry form where the user can save their input and this would run an insert query to insert the fields into the database table. First I started to create a new database in SQL Server management studio. I created this database the exact same way that I would for a web application (pretty much just give it a name and accept all other default settings) to  create the new database. But, I can't figure out how to connect to this instance from Visual Basic 2010. When I try to add new connection, I choose Microsoft Sql Server Database File(SqlClient). but when I browse for my Database file, I end up with an Access is denied error. I messed around a little with this and did some research but nothing has worked and I'm already running Visual Basic as an Admin.

The second thing I tried which seems like it is closer to working is I went to add new item and added a Service-based Database to my project and configured the table through Visual Basics Database Explorer. This properly configured my database as far as building the tables. Now, after configuring a DataSet and Table Adapter and adding the Fill and Insert Query to the table adapter I try to call my Insert Query (was configured in the Wizard) the query gets the correct values for the parameters but when I try to view the the table through Database Explorer there are not any rows added to the table, it is blank.

Here is the Insert query that is configured int the TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard...

```
INSERT INTO DispatchType
                     (NonEmergency, Emergency, NormalCall, WaitReturn, GWWheelchair, PatientWheelchair, Stretcher, ChiefComplaint)
VALUES        (@NonEmergency,@Emergency,@NormalCall,@WaitReturn,@GWWheelchair,@PatientWheelchair,@Stretcher,@ChiefComplaint)
```

Here is how I'm calling the insert query...

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Office-Admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Dispatch\Dispatch\Dispatch.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    conn.Open()
    Me.DispatchTypeTableAdapter.InsertQuery(RadioButton4.Checked, RadioButton5.Checked, RadioButton7.Checked, RadioButton6.Checked, RadioButton16.Checked, RadioButton15.Checked, RadioButton17.Checked, TextBox1.Text)
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

I tried it at first without adding the sql connection string and opening and closing but even with this, it runs through with no errors but I don't see the values added to the table anywhere.

So I need help with how to properly configure a sql server database with my windows forms application so that multiple users will be able to run the application on multiple PC's and all of the data gets stored into One Local Database. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong but I obviously don't have it properly configured. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the configuration of your QSL server, it's that you are never actually executing the SQL statement.

Instead of:

```
Me.DispatchTypeTableAdapter.InsertQuery(RadioButton4.Checked, RadioButton5.Checked, RadioButton7.Checked, RadioButton6.Checked, RadioButton16.Checked, RadioButton15.Checked, RadioButton17.Checked, TextBox1.Text)
```

Do something like this:

```
Dim command as new sqlcommand(conn)
command.queryText = "INSERT INTO DispatchType NonEmergency, Emergency, NormalCall, WaitReturn, GWWheelchair, PatientWheelchair, Stretcher, ChiefComplaint) VALUES (@NonEmergency,@Emergency, @NormalCall,@WaitReturn,@GWWheelchair,@PatientWheelchair,@Stretcher,@ChiefComplaint)"
command.parameters.addWithValue("@NonEmergency", RadioButton4.Checked) 'Repeat for each parameter
command.executeNonQuery
```

Comment: I tried this and I still don't see anything in the database table. Let me ask you this, for an application to be used by multiple PC's should I be trying to connect to a Local Database Stored on one machine in the Program Files/MSSQLServer folder, or should I have an instance of that database stored in my application folder VBApplication/ApplicationFolder/database.mdf? Forgive me if my technical language isn't quit right.

Comment: Because I think I found the problem which was, when it created my connection string for me since I used the wizard, It didn't put the right file location so I changed it to this `<add name="Dispatch.My.MySettings.DispatchConnectionString1"
            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Dispatch.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: If you want shared data across multiple machines you will need an actual SQL Server instance that all that machines connect to.  You will want to download SQL Server express and install it on  a computer that all the other computers can talk to.  You will then need to create the database on that computer and then change the connection string in your application t point to that computer instead of the local one.  You could also theoretically use a cloud based service like Microsoft Azure to host the database without needing one on site.

Comment: Would I change the DataSource= Portion to the database path or would I change the AttachDbFilename= to the database path?

Comment: This is an example of a valid connection string from on of my apps. "data source=hdcvs-food;initial catalog=FoodSafetyDevelopment;user id=PAFoodSafetyAppUser;password=Password;". Data-source is the host name or IP address of the central server, initial catalog is the name of the database on that server.  user id and password should be set to credentials on that server that have permission to write to the database.

Comment: Ok so if I wanted to connect to my machines Sql Server Database I would change `DataSource=.\SQLExpress` to something like `DataSource=Office-Admin` which would be the host PC name?

Comment: And maybe one last thing... In my DataSet Properties, what should I set the 'Copy To Output Directory' property as? should I copy always or do not copy?

Comment: Yes, as long as "office-admin" resolves to the name of the sql server from every computer that needs to access it.  You can test by dropping to a command line and entering "ping Office-Admin".  If all computers return the same address you should be good.

Comment: Depending on how you installed Sql Server, you will have to enable the TCP/IP endpoint for it.  This should walk you through it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Ok thanks so much for your help, I believe you have me on the right track now. While I got you here, maybe you know how to fix the problem I have now when I try to open the page that the connection is on, i get the error 'Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed.' My server is configured to use windows authentication.